# Equivalent of ChangeNotifierProvider widget in Riverpod

Tags: flutter, provider, state-management, flutter-change-notifier, riverpod

Is there a widget equivalent of the ChangeNotifierProvider widget of Provider in Riverpod?

The use case is to create a provider only when a page whose parent widget is ChangeNotifierProvider/or a page that has ChangeNotifierProvider in its widget tree has been pushed unto the Navigator stack using `create`. I would like the provider to be automatically disposed when the page is popped and the ChangeNotifierProvider widget is removed from the widget tree just like in Provider.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Riverpod has a `ChangeNotifierProvider` too, so you can use that.

As for the "I would like the provider to be automatically disposed when the page is popped", this functionality is instead implemented using [autoDispose](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/auto_dispose)

So in the end, the syntax would be:

```dart
class MyNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {}

final myNotifierProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose<MyNotifier>((ref) {
  return MyNotifier();
});

...

class MyWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    MyNotifier myNotifier = watch(myNotifierProvider);
  }
}
```

With this, when all the widgets using `MyNotifier` are destroyed (aka when the route is popped), then `MyNotifier` will be disposed.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually right in the docs (https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/auto_dispose). Still getting a hang of it ‍♂️.

Comment: Ok, but ".when" doesnt work with a ChangeNotifierProvider, right?